# Add HTML To The Contents Of A Div Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently generating the following div:

```
<div class="dates" >November 18, 2011 7:30 pm November 19, 2011 7:00 pm  </div>
```

I want to use jQuery to on the load of the page change the div to read like this:

```
<div class="dates" >November 18, 2011 7:30 pm<br />November 19, 2011 7:00 pm<br /></div>
```

Wanted to get jQuery to change instances within the div of `pm` to `pm<br />`

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're generating the div, why don't you insert the <br />'s at that time?

Comment: @SteveWellens, Ha! Excellent point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.dates').html($('.dates').html().replace('pm', 'pm<br />'));`

http://jsfiddle.net/jLcKa/

Comment: @user1038620, would you never have am in place of pm?

Answer (score 1):

you can use regular expressions sometihng like

```
var replaced = $("div.dates").html();
replaced = replaced.replace(/pm/gi, "pm <br />")
$("div.dates").html(replaced);
```

Comment: have to be VERY careful though with using that regex, because it will find any and all instances of pm (globally ignoring case) and replace it with pm <br />

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dates').append($('<br />'));
```

Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Just instead of removing the `:` add pm.

[Replace text in string within an element after a specific character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175484/replace-text-in-string-within-an-element-after-a-specific-character)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wn5CB/)

```
$(function(){
    var dates = $(".dates").html();
    var regex = /([ap]m) /gi;

    dates = dates.replace(regex, "$1<br>");

    $(".dates").html(dates);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
$(function() {
  var dates = $('.dates');
  var html = dates.html(); 
  html = html.replace(/ (pm) /gi, ' $1 <br /> ');
  dates.html(html);
});
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qv37N/)

The above code will match all elements with a 'dates' class, and insert a break element after each ' pm ' that it finds, whilst respecting the casing of the original pm text.